# Get storage size of postgresql table (and not of toast-table)

Tags: postgresql

I'm using a postgresql-DB (9.3) on a Ubuntu-system and have some rather large tables that contain binary data blobs. I now want to get the storage size of these tables to find a starting point for optimizing my database.

I have found many scripts that list the size of each table (e.g. [here in the postgresql wiki](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Disk_Usage)) but this is my result:

```
                          relation                           |    size    
-------------------------------------------------------------+------------
 pg_toast.pg_toast_18142                                     | 1793 MB
 pg_toast.pg_toast_18206                                     | 71 MB
 pg_toast.pg_toast_18142_index                               | 20 MB
 public.crane_exposure                                       | 6864 kB
 public.clamp_log                                            | 1088 kB
 public.Stored_objects                                       | 888 kB
```

I don't care about the tables in the MB range, but I rather want to know which tables contribute to the 1.8 GB.

Can someone tell me how I can get a more detailed list of the sizes?

Comment: The `toast` tables _are_ the blob storage. Do you want to find out to which table `pg_toast_18142 ` [belongs to](http://talkpostgres.com/threads/find-toast-tables-in-postgresql.7/)?

Comment: You can alternatively use `pg_total_relation_size()` which reports the size of the table _including_ TOAST tables and indexes.

Comment: pg_total_relation_size() was the thing I was looking for. Thanks!